# Signifyd Issues : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, order-status, signifyd

I have configured Signifyd in my store and it is working fine. I have configured it like if the order is approved for guarantee then invoice generate automatically.

Check this screenshot,
[image]

Now, Since last 5-6 days, There are some 12 orders out of 40 which are not sent to Signifyd. So, Signifyd score and Signifyd Decision is not available for those orders only.
Check this screenshot,

[image]

So, Is there any particular reason why this issue happened? What step I should take further?
Please give me appropriate solution.

**Note:** I have checked Signifyd API status and it was fine. https://status.signifyd.com/

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: In my case, There are some order placed if customer enter the wrong CC details. So, Signifyd can not validate those transaction.